# Como executar scripts no F12 pelo Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Eu queria saber como faço pra executar um script pelo F12 ( Ferramentas de Desenvolvedor ) pelo Selenium, eu queria que ele abrisse o F12, depois iria até o Console e lá colocar lá o script, eu já tentei driver.execute_script('script'), mais só funciona se eu tiver o F12 aberto no Google.

O que eu tenho até agora é isso

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URL_SITE)

browser.execute_script("var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');iframe.onload = function(){var ifrLocalStorage = iframe.contentWindow.localStorage; return ifrLocalStorage.getItem('token');};iframe.src = 'about:blank';document.body.appendChild(iframe);")
```

Comment: Olá Ped, o `execute_script` não precisa do DevTools aberto, provavelmente você esta fazendo alguma confusão.

Comment: Vou ja olhou as actionschains? Por elas da pra vc pressionar o F12 https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Comment: Consegui @BielSousa, eu coloquei na options pra abrir com options.add_argument('auto-open-devtools-for-tabs'), obrigado pela resposta